Yup Formik Validation Not Working with react-number-format for custom component
I’m integrating react-number-format into a Formik form for handling numeric inputs with formatting (e.g., decimal points and thousands separators). However, after integrating react-number-format, my Yup validation no longer seems to work as expected.
import { Formik, Field, useField } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { NumericFormat } from 'react-number-format';

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  amount: Yup.number()
    .required("Amount is required")
    .positive("Amount must be positive")
    .max(20000000, "Maximum loan amount is 20,000,000"),
});

const NumberField = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);

  const borderColor = !meta.touched
    ? "border-gray"
    : meta.touched && meta.error
    ? "border-red-500"
    : "border-gray";

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex items-center border border-gray rounded-md">
        <NumericFormat
          {...field}
          {...props}
          thousandSeparator
          decimalScale={2}
          fixedDecimalScale
          allowNegative={false}
          className="w-full py-2 px-2 border-none focus:outline-[#6DCCA0] outline-1 rounded-md"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Formik Form
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    amount: "",
  }}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={values => {
    console.log(values);
  }}
>
  {({ values, setFieldValue, errors, touched }) => (
    <Form>
      <div className="mb-4 md:mb-6 md:pb-4 lg:pb-1">
        <label htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
        <Field
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="USD"
          name="amount"
          component={NumberField}
          value={values.amount}
          onValueChange={(values) => {
            const { floatValue } = values;
            setFieldValue("amount", floatValue);
          }}
        />
        {errors.amount && touched.amount && (
          <div className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">{errors.amount}</div>
        )}
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>


I also did some research and realised that setting the value and onChange in the  might be what is causing this issue since Formik handles this natively so I tried handing the onChange in the NumberField function but this breaks the code
  const NumberField = ({ name, ...props }: any) => {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);

    const borderColor = !meta.touched
      ? "border-gray"
      : meta.touched && meta.error
      ? "border-red-500"
      : "border-gray";

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex items-center border border-gray rounded-md">
          <NumericFormat
            {...field}
            {...props}
            thousandSeparator
            decimalScale={2}
            fixedDecimalScale
            allowNegative={false}
            className="w-full py-2 px-2 border-none focus:outline-[#6DCCA0] outline-1 rounded-md"
            onValueChange={(values: any) => {
              const { floatValue } = values;
              props.setFieldValue(name, floatValue);
              // helpers.setValue(floatValue ?? "");
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

                          <FormItem
                            label="Amount"
                            className="mb-4 md:mb-6 md:pb-4 lg:pb-1"
                            invalid={errors.amount && touched.amount}
                            errorMessage={errors.amount}
                          >


                            <Field
                              autoComplete="off"
                              placeholder="USD"
                              name="amount"
                              component={NumberField}
                            />
                            
                            </Field>{" "} */}
                            {/* new */}
                          </FormItem>

After integrating react-number-format and setting up the NumberField component, the validation schema I’ve set up using Yup is not working as expected. I want the YUP validation to show when users enter a negative number or above the YUP specified amount
